# Antiword converts .doc into an empy .txt file

Tags: python, doc, file-conversion

I am new to python and trying to convert a .doc extension file into a .txt file with content on a linux server

I set the linux directory persion to 777

On running the below script return an empty output_file.txt with permission 644

Please help me to fix it

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import call

input_word_file = "file500kb.docx"
output_text_file = "output_file.txt"
os.system('antiword %s > %s' % (input_word_file, output_text_file))
# subprocess.call('antiword %s > %s' % (input_word_file, output_text_file))
# call('antiword %s > %s' % (input_word_file, output_text_file))
# subprocess.check_output('antiword %s > %s' % (input_word_file, output_text_file))
```

I was trying alternatives for os.system that are in comments.

Comment: To make sure that the problem is Python related, what does same command produces when passed directly at command prompt level with the same file?

Comment: Does it work when antiword is executed directly from command line?

Comment: Yes, when I executed the file directly on command line on my local machine it worked. I get a converted file with texts. When I run it on the linux remote server it convert into an empty file. I execute the file by PHP using exec() function

Comment: ".. a .doc extension file into a .txt file ..". But you do not feed it a **.doc** type – you feed it a **.docx**. "The utility only supports the old 'doc' format, not the new xml based 'docx'" – [source](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/antiword/index.html)

Comment: Okay I am sorry that I mentioned docx file in the question. The situation is same when I run it for a .doc file as well, it creates empty .txt file.

Comment: You can't run it directly from command line on the remote server (e. g. by ssh)?

Comment: I can excute .py files by PHP using exec("python docconvert.py"); I ran similar files for different solutions and got output. On running docconvert.py , the file executes and creates and empty .txt file.

Comment: In the same directory as *file500kb.docx*?

Comment: As an aside, I believe the subprocess library is recommended over the use of `os.system`.

Comment: @pacholik Yes, on the same directory

Comment: @AMC I tried using subprocess still no results. Is subprocess works for you on linux server?